# SDP relaxation of a non-convex quadratically-constrained quadratic program

Tags: convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, qcqp, relaxations

I am very new to SDP and SDP solvers. I have a semi definite program of the following form 
$$\min_{x,X}\  Q\bullet X+c^Tx$$
$$\text{s.t. } Q^k \bullet X + (c^k)^T x =b^k , \ k=1,2, \dots,m \\
\quad   a^p(a^p)^T \bullet X=(d^p)^2 \\
(a^p)^Tx=d^p, \ p=1,2,\dots, q \\
ee^T-xe^T-ex^T+X \geq 0 \\
X \geq 0 \\
X \geq xx^T $$
How to convert it to a form so that it can be solved by using CVX or SeDuMi? I am unaware of the process/form. Any pointers to helpful examples or guides will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I changed $\displaystyle min_{x,X}$ to $\displaystyle \min_{x,X}$.  Just add a backslash.  This affects not only italicization and positions of subscripts, but also spacing before and after $\min$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you for the correction. Do you have any idea how to solve the problem ?

Comment: What does the big black dot mean?

Comment: The big black dot means the inner product of the matrices A, B defined as $$ A \bullet B = \sum_i \sum_j A_{ij} B_{ij}$$

Comment: What exactly is making it difficult for you to express this in CVX? Here's an exercise. Suppose $X$ and $x$ are just *constants*; that is, a standard numeric array, and a standard numeric vector. How would you compute the value of each constraint or objective expression in MATLAB? For instance, the objective function is `trace(Q*X)+c'*x`.

Comment: @MichaelGrant The problem is with  the constraints of the form $$ ee^T-xe^T-ex^T+X \geq 0 \\ X \geq xx^T $$. Matlab gives "Warning: This linear matrix inequality appears to be unsymmetric. This is
very likely an error that will produce unexpected results. Please check
the LMI; and, if necessary, re-enter the model. " for the first constraint and "Disciplined Convex Programming Error" for the second type of error.

Comment: Now see, you should have supplied those details right from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your comments, the problem is the fact that you need to express the constraint $X \succeq xx^T$ as a linear matrix inequality. As written, of course, it is not, because it is quadratic in $x$. But we can actually use a Schur complement approach:
$$X \succeq xx^T \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad \begin{bmatrix} X & x \\ x^T & 1 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$
This transformation is an important one to know whether you are using CVX, any other convex modeling software, or just attempting to call an SDP solver like SeDuMi directly.

Note that $X\succeq 0$ is implied by $X \succeq xx^T$, so you can drop $X\succeq 0$ from your problem completely.

The other problem you're having with CVX is probably because you haven't declared $X$ to be a symmetric matrix. You'll need to read the manual about that. [CVX has its own forum](http://ask.cvxr.com), and further software-specific questions should go there.

Comment: It worked.Thank you very much sir for taking out time and helping me.